# Javascript Regex to match bounded text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this:

```
....foo..bar....
```

foo and bar can be any text at all.

It could also be:

```
anypreamble....foo..bar....anypostamble
```

I'm trying to match just foo and just bar but I keep matching the entire thing.

Here's some code:

```
var s = "this....AAAAAAAAAA..BBBBCD....that";

console.log(s.replace(/\.{4}.+\.{2}(.+)\.{4}/g, 'X'));
```

I would expect the above to give me: thisAAAAAAAAAAXthat, instead it gives: thisXthat.

Can you help?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vfkzdg9y/1/

Comment: you're replacing the entire match with `'X'`, try using a capture group and backreference.

Comment: I thought the (.+) was the capture group...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the two strings (foo and bar) separated with X, you can use:

```
var s = "this....AAAAAAAAAA..BBBBCD....that";

console.log(s.replace(/[^\.]*\.{4}([^\.]+)\.{2}([^\.]+)\.{4}.*/g, '$1X$2'));
```

Yields

> AAAAAAAAAAXBBBBCD

You could also use:

```
console.log(s.replace(/[^\.]*\.{4}(.+)\.{2}(.+)\.{4}.*/g, '$1X$2'));
```

Which yields

> AAAAAAAAAAXBBBB.CD

for your second example.

Comment: This is good, but the text could literally be anything including fullstops, so I can't use the negate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RegExp` `/(\.{2}\w+)(?=\.{4}\w+$)|\./g`to match two consecutive `.` characters followed by alphanumeric characters , if followed by four `.` characters followed by alphanumeric characters followed by end of string ; replace `.` with empty string, else return `"X"` for captured match

```
s.replace(/(\.{2}\w+)(?=\.{4}\w+$)|\./g, function(match) {
  return match === "." ? "" : "X"
})
```